# How can I use JNA StdCallCallback which accepts array of int within a structure?

Tags: java, arrays, struct, callback, jna

Let us consider that we need to pass a structured form of callbacks to native code dll.
One of the callbacks has the following form in C notation:

```
int myfunc (int arg1,int* arg2,int arg3,int arg4);//it is marked as stdcall in real app
```

Here arg2 is an array of ints. arg1 determines the number of elements in arg2.

Here is Java code:

```
 public class TRCallbackCollection extends Structure{
       public int fieldsCount;    
       public StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback myfunc;
//...
    }
//...
TRCallbackCollection callbacks= new   TRCallbackCollection();
callbacks.fieldsCount = 7;       
callbacks.myfunc = new StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback(){
 public int callback (int arg1, int[] arg2,int arg3,int arg4) {            
  return 0;
 }
};
```

I've got the followin error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure field "myfunc" was
>   declared as interface
>   com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary$StdCallCallback, which is not
>   supported within a Structure,

when I try to init native dll with the instance of TRCallbackCollection structure:

```
lib.InitKernel(callbacks,5);
```

Other callbacks work fine. I think that the problem is linked with `int[] arg2` in method. How should I transform it and use as the array within callback?

Comment: From what I understand, the exception clearly says that `StdCallCallback` interface cannot be declared as a field in a Structure. You have to derive/extend a callback field from `StdCallCallback` or `Callback` interface just like other callbacks. http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jna.user/4130

Comment: Other StdCallCallback fields worked!Fortunately, I've solved the problem. I've used `Pointer arg2` instead of `int[] arg2`.

Comment: The error message is misleading; the failure probably occurred when attempting to map native types into the callback signature (primitive arrays are not permissible as callback arguments without providing custom callback parameter conversion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Success; other StdCallCallback fields worked!

Fortunately, I've solved the problem. I used `Pointer arg2` instead of `int[] arg2`.